# can't enter "d" "e" or "f" with sendkeys on Safari 17.3.1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, sendkeys, safaridriver

I'm using safaridriver, included with Safari 17.3.1 (19617.2.4.11.12). I'm not having problems with the latest versions of Chrome, Edge or Firefox.

I have a web page with just a textarea input. If I try to enter "def" (either one character at a time, as part of a longer string, or just as "def") with SendKeys, the letters "d", "e" and "f" don't appear in the textarea. The html for the web page is just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form action="action_page.php">
      <textarea id="input" name="textInput" rows="10" cols="80">
      <textarea>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

If I send a string with the characters "d", "e" or "f", those characters don't appear in the text input.

I've tried using just input.SendKeys(text), I've tried entering one character at a time (with or without a delay of anywhere from 100ms to two seconds) using SendKeys, and I've tried Actions to enter the text. I can enter "d" "e" or "f" when I type, but not by code. Here's the simplest of the versions I've tried:

```
input.Click();
input.SendKeys(""); // this seems to help in other cases, otherwise the first character doesn't appear
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
{
    input.SendKeys(text[i].ToString());
}
```

This is making me feel pretty incompetent...

Comment: sounds like a keyboard language problem.  Do you have any foreign keyboard languages installed?

Comment: Nope. I thought it might be something in my Keyboard Settings, but I don't find anything there that jumps out at me. I'm not really a Mac user, though, so maybe I just don't see the issue. I also found that capital Q somewhere in a longer string acts like command+shift+Q and I intermittently get asked which mail client I want to use or I get the browser history displayed. Entering strings a character at a time fixes those issues, but it did make me wonder if I had the Keyboard settings wrong.

Comment: I think you'd check  System Preference-> Language Text-> Input Sources.  Make sure English is the default.  (not a Mac user myself... but this sounds like a similar problem that's come up in the past for Ukrainian keyboard in Windows/Selenium)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I did check languages (only English is installed), then I also checked other keyboard settings as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe send input using JS?

If `SendKeys()` doesn't work for some reason, you can use JS to do the job for you. Like this:

```java
input.Click();
input.SendKeys(""); // this seems to help in other cases, otherwise the first character doesn't appear
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
{
    driver.executeScript("var e = arguments[0];e.value = e.value+\"" + text[i].ToString() + "\";",input);
}
```

BTW I'm not 100% sure this is valid in Java, I do it in Python and it works, maybe Java syntax will differ with Selenium here, but you got the idea.

Comment: Doh, yeah, that's worth a try, at least. I use JS pretty often; I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me for this. Monday... I'm not working on the weekend. :-)

Comment: Have a nice weekend XD

Comment: Sadly, no joy there. I used:

((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", elem, text);

text was "abcdefg"
I get "abcg" in the text box. 
What is special about those three characters???

Comment: To be honest, it works pretty fine on any other browser. I can't try safari cuz I don't have mac unfortunately.

Comment: That's just what I see. It works on everything but Safari... Thanks for a good suggestion though.